# All possible combination of columns in a table with conditional data of other tables

Tags: sql-server

I want the result as a combination of two columns color and size of `LinkedColorSize` table in SQL Server. I have three tables `Color`, `Size` and `LinkedColorSize`.

I have a table `Color`:

| ColorName |
| --- |
| Red |
| Green |

The second table is `Size`:

| SizeName |
| --- |
| Small |
| Large |

And a third table `LinkedColorSize`:

| LinkID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Large |
| 2 | Green | 0 |

In this example, I’m unable to find any solution. In the table 0 stands for all, which means if 0 in the Color column then it means all colors from the Color table, and 0 in the Size column means all sizes from the Size table, So the Small and Large both should be mapped with Green.

The expected result for the second table is something like.

| Color | Size |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Large |
| Green | Small |
| Green | Large |

And the `LinkedColorSize` table also can be:

| LinkID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Large |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

OR

| LinkID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

OR

| LinkID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Small |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |

OR anything else....

I will be thankful for your help.

Comment: Can you share please query that you used?

Comment: For first example table

SELECT a.Color, b.Size FROM LinkedColorSize a
CROSS APPLY LinkedColorSize b
where a.LinkID = '11' AND b.LinkID = '11'

But not able to understand for a second example

Comment: How do you get 12 rows in the expected result ? Can you identify which row is from which row in `LinkedColorSize` ?

Comment: @Squirrel I have corrected the question with more explanation.

Comment: You should include a expected result and explanation for each of the 3 scenario. Anyway, you may take a look at my answer see if is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN`. `on LinkedColorSize.Color = Color.Color`. For cases where `Color = 0` in the `LinkedColorSize, The join condition` Color = '0'`will effectively making it`CROSS JOIN`

---

```
select l.*, c.Color, s.Size
from   LinkedColorSize l
       inner join Color c  on l.Color = c.Color or l.Color = '0'
       inner join Size s   on l.Size  = s.Size  or l.Size  = '0'
order by l.LinkID, c.Color, s.Size
```

---

Note : in the fiddle demo, i have change the LinkID so that it can clearly identify how the row in the result correspond to the source (third table)

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f80468becb9311ba77bbdba70a95f350)